# How would I add a timeout to a jQuery function I've written

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timeout

I'm new to jQuery/coding and need some help, I have this function to add a class to a button, but I want to have it so that after 10 seconds the function is undone. Is there a way to add a timeout to the function or should I write another function to remove the class I added after a delay.

The function looks like this:

```
 jQuery("#ntc-web-main .load-on-click").click(function() {
   
        jQuery(this).text("Loading").removeClass("btn-default btn-primary btn-success btn-info btn-danger btn-link").addClass("btn-warning");

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after making the first change, set up a timer that runs a function after 10 seconds that does the reverse:

```
jQuery("#ntc-web-main .load-on-click").click(function() {

    jQuery(this).text("Loading").removeClass("btn-default btn-primary btn-success btn-info btn-danger btn-link").addClass("btn-warning");

    setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery(this).text("Loading").removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-default btn-primary btn-success btn-info btn-danger btn-link");
    }, 10000);

});
```